# Dropdown list element not found using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, contains

I'm having a problem selecting the drop down list using the ID, since that it's dynamic.

There's a fixed part in the ID, so I tried using `contains`, but I can't seem to get the hang of it.

My Code Part using selenium webdriver java:

```
Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[contains(@id,'_listSelect')]")));
```

Dropdown HTML using firebug (the select part):

```
<div id="00B70000008WMdr_topNav" class="topNav primaryPalette">
    <div class="controls">
        <img class="pageTitleIcon" title="Case" alt="Case" src="/img/s.gif">
        <select id="00B70000008WMdr_listSelect" class="title" title="View:" onchange="ListViewport.instances['00B70000008WMdr'].showFeedOrListView(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="fcf">
           ...
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try //select[contains(@id,'_listSelect')] in Chrome f12 search bar before implementing it in your code and check whether it is highlight the element in the DOM

or i believe the name is static  for your select tag if yes try with that.

Comment: Do you have any idea if its not highlighted how can I get that? I think my problem is in this specific part

Comment: i tired it and it highlights the part.. i have no idea what could be wrong

Comment: How many matches does it find?  You may have to further narrow-down your xpath if there are multiple matches by using an array or perhaps trying to search using something else, like perhaps `//select[@title='View:']`

Comment: @MonnaKhaled let me know the count it shows while highlighting in chrome and share the error you are getting while running the script.

Comment: @SandeepRaulo only one count.. i dont know what's wrong.. really

Comment: @MonnaKhaled Check whether the dropdown is inside a frame else update the question with your error log or share the link so that i can try from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select dropdown = new Select (driver.findElement(By.css("select[id$='_listSelect']")))
```

Comment: Does css do partial matching on id's?  I don't think your solution would work.  Plus the inner double quotes should be escaped or changed to single quotes.